# How to get super class delegate and update the variable in super class from subclass

Tags: iphone

```
 @interface first{

     nsstring one;
     second secondobject;

 }

 @interface second{

     nsstring two;

 }
```

in the above classes from second class I want to update the first class "one" string.

I knew that we can update the "two" string from the first class

but I want to update the string "one" from second class

- should not use appdelegate
- should not use inheritance

*I want to know like our AppDelegate has the `[[uiapplication sharedapplication]delegate]`

by getting above delegate of appdelegate we can access properties of appDelegate class

Like this how can we can get the delegate for first class and access the properties of first class from the second class.

if any pictorial tutorial for tree structure please specify the link

here is my structure

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't really understand the meaning of delegates and what they are used for.
In your example class first aggregates (contains) instance of class second. It means that the reference to that class is an ivar. You can access all public members, properties and methods of that instance from class first.
  If you want to access the ivars of the superclass then you can do that like they were declared in the child class. 
  Delegates are used when you need to notify another object about something during execution. Objects usually have weak references (they don't retain) to delegates.

So i think the best choice for you would be to read some good book about object oriented programming. This is really good [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0805353402) about that

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a pointer from the first class to the second, and the second can use this to call methods or access data members in the first class.

Or if `first` will be a singleton class (like `UIApplication`), you can set up a class method (like `sharedApplication`) that `second` can call to get a reference to the `first` object.

Generally, structuring iPhone apps using the [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) pattern helps to reduce these kinds of tangles.